# How do we configure jdk in scripted pipeline for Jenkins using groovy script?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Recently we upgraded Jenkins from jdk 8 to jdk 11. But our repo was based on java 8 and while trying to gradle build our project it’s failing because of the version. So I installed jdk 8 in Jenkins. How do I specify the job to use that pre installed jdk 8 in scripted pipeline using groovy script.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a custom tool installed for specifying the jdk version used.

```
node {
  jdk = tool name: 'JDK17'
  env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdk}"

  echo "jdk installation path is: ${jdk}"

  // next 2 are equivalents
  sh "${jdk}/bin/java -version"

  // note that simple quote strings are not evaluated by Groovy
  // substitution is done by shell script using environment
  sh '$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version'
}
```